Add the hover on the header in datagrid
I need to add the hover over the column header. I added the code below on ItemDataBound and ItemCreated. However the hover didn't work
There is my aspx page:
<asp:templatecolumn HeaderText="# S">                                       
  <itemtemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </itemtemplate>
</asp:templatecolumn>

There is my vb code:
    Select Case e.Item.ItemType 
  Case ListItemType.Header
    e.Item.Cells(6).Text = "<a href='#' title='" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ColumnHeader") & "'>" &  e.Item.Cells(6).Text & "</a>"
End Select

Would you tell me how to fix it. Thanks in advance

You can set the hover text for most elements by setting the tooltip.
So, say this datagrid:
  <asp:DataGrid ID="GHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
     DataKeyField="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" Width="45%"
      OnItemDataBound="GHotels_ItemDataBound">

      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="First" DataField="FirstName" runat="server" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Last" DataField="LastName" runat="server" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="City" DataField="City" runat="server" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="HotelName" DataField="HotelName" runat="server" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description" runat="server" />

        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Edit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdEdit" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl="~/Content/edit2.png" Width="48"
                    />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>

        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl="~/Content/trashcan1.png" width="48"
                    OnClick="cmdDelete_Click"
                    OnClientClick="return mydelprompt(this);"
                    />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>

      </Columns>
  </asp:DataGrid>

Our code to load the DataGrid:
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack = False Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If


End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA
        ORDER BY HotelName"

    GHotels.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
    GHotels.DataBind()

End Sub

And our row data bound event:
Protected Sub GHotels_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As DataGridItemEventArgs)


    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Header Then

        e.Item.Cells(3).ToolTip = "This is the hotel name"
        e.Item.Cells(4).ToolTip = $"Description{vbCrLf}And options for hotel"

    End If

End Sub

And the result is now this:


@CDVS, thanks. It works
